# Looking to create panel data that shows values for each month. Need help filling in months which no values are present

Tags: python, pandas

Here is how my data is structured:

```
Date       Month Year Value
2018/10/3  10    2018 30
2018/9/1   9     2018 3
2018/7/3   7     2018 3
```

This is how I would like it to be:

```
Month Year Value
10    2018 30
9     2018 3
8     2018 0
7     2018 3
```

I'm really stumped on how to proceed. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is `resample`

```
s=df.resample('M').mean()
s.Month=s.index.month
s.Year=s.index.year
s.Value.fillna(0,inplace=True)
s
Out[403]: 
            Month  Year  Value
Date                          
2018-07-31      7  2018    3.0
2018-08-31      8  2018    0.0
2018-09-30      9  2018    3.0
2018-10-31     10  2018   30.0
```